# Haskell error "Could not deduce (Integral Float) arising from a use of.."

Tags: types

I am new to Haskell and am trying to calculate the standard deviation of a lists of lists of floats. Ubuntu 18.04, ghc 8.0.2. I am getting the following error which I have googled and still don't understand what "Integral Float" is exactly.

```
*Main> let z = stdDev 0 1 y x
<interactive>:250:9: error:
• Could not deduce (Integral Float) arising from a use of ‘stdDev’
  from the context: Floating a
    bound by the inferred type of z :: Floating a => [a]
    at <interactive>:250:5-38
• In the expression: stdDev 0 (length (head (x))) y x
  In an equation for ‘z’: z = stdDev 0 (length (head (x))) y x
```

Code:

```
-- i is start index, l is length of each list, ms is list of means, 
--    xs is Matrix
stdDev i l ms xs
     | i < l     = sqrt(fromIntegral(sumOfMinusMeans i (ms!!i) xs) / 
                             fromIntegral(l)):(stdDev (i+1) l ms xs)
     | otherwise = []

--i is index, m is mean for the index
sumOfMinusMeans i m (x:xs)
     | xs == []     = (x!!i - m)**2
     | i < length x = (x!!i - m)**2 + (sumOfMinusMeans i m xs)
     | otherwise    = 0
```

Types:

```
*Main> :t stdDev
stdDev
  :: (Floating a1, Floating a, Integral a1) =>
     Int -> Int -> [a1] -> [[a1]] -> [a]

*Main> :t sumOfMinusMeans
sumOfMinusMeans :: (Eq t, Floating t) => Int -> t -> [[t]] -> t
```

Variables:

```
*Main> y
[380.0,1.0]
*Main> x
[[600.0,1.0],[400.0,1.0],[170.0,1.0],[430.0,1.0],[300.0,1.0]]
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. I needed specify the function types and add a 'fromIntegral' and some of my algorithm logic was wrong.

```
stdDev :: Int -> Float -> [Float] -> [[Float]] -> [Float]
stdDev i l ms xs
    | fromIntegral(i) < length(head(xs)) = sqrt((sumOfMinusMeans i (ms!!i) xs) 
                                               / l): (stdDev (i+1) l ms xs)
    | otherwise                          = []


sumOfMinusMeans :: Int -> Float -> [[Float]] -> Float
sumOfMinusMeans i m (x:xs)
    | xs == []  = (x!!i - m)**2
    | otherwise = (x!!i - m)**2 + (sumOfMinusMeans i m xs)
```